# Need to hide/remove volume bar in WordPress Default Player to give more room to progress bar

Tags: audio, customization

I am a rookie and I am trying to make my players to look like [this](http://www.voiceofjaybritton.com/) , but I have been trying for a couple of days and all I can do is hide it with

```
.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider,
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

but when I do this,  the space where the volume bar was is not removed and the minute progress bar dissapears.

In other words, I would like to give the minute progress bar , the space occupied by the volume bar.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours... Here is the solution to my own question

```
.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider { display: none !important; }
.mejs-controls div.mejs-time-rail { width: 70px !important; }
.mejs-time-total { width: 60px !important; }
```

Now my audio player is exactly like the example provided. I hope this helps somebody else.